# What's the difference between using a script tag to call a file and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Aside from the obvious use of jQuery, is there a difference between calling a script into a page with:

`<script src="script.js">`

vs

```
ajax({
    url: 'script.js,
    dataType: 'script'
})
```

Comment: When using a script as defined here, it is always read and executed during page load time. When you use Ajax, that isn't necessarily so.

Comment: `<script>` is not subject to CORS restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using an ajax request you are expecting an answer (which in this case is the file as string), where as when you add a script tag it will try to run the file or add its functions to the global scope.

see here in [datatype](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: *"where as when you add a script tag it will try to run the file or add its functions to the global scope."* The browser will **always** run the script. And that's the only thing it does. The script itself may add functions to the global scope, but it could also do anything else really. It doesn't seem to be useful to list only *one* of the infinite things JavaScript can do.